# How to change code to apply to a named sheet tab, instead of the first sheet tab in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a great piece of code which copies out a row of data to the a certain sheet in a spreadsheet when the value 'Assigned' is entered in another column. So the user will select the sheet it must move to, and then changes the status to assigned and it gets moved out. It works great but now I want to modify it to work on a different sheet in that spreadsheet. How do i change the code to work on a different sheet that i specify instead of just the first one? I have pasted my working code below that applies to the first tab. I want to make another script to apply to the other tabs to work with different values and move to another. I am very new to this, so would appreciate any help.

I know I need to update the ss.getActiveSheet() to include getSheetByName(); but im not sure how to edit the end bit of the code to get it to work.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = e.source;
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.range;

   // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form 
   responses sheet
    var actionCol = 19;
    var nameCol = 18;

    // Get the row and column of the active cell.
    var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
    var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

    // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
    // -1 to drop our action/status column
    var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

    // if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
    if (e.value == "Assigned" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority 
    column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 
colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      // or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
     }
     }
     }
```

Comment: The `onEdit()` function will trigger anytime a user edits _any_ sheet. The `if` statement makes sure that the changes happen only under certain conditions. So don't think you need to include the name of a sheet. If I have understood the problem incorrectly, please consider posting a sample sheet with any private data removed.

Comment: Hello! Thank you SO much for your answer. So I think that is what the problem is, the fact that I need the same script working on different sheets based on different values - so when i do that, it breaks the others. 
So on Sheet 1, i need the row moved to the selected sheet if the status is set to "assigned". On sheet two, i want a menu option that runs a similar script, but only looks at sheet 2, and moves the row if status is set to "Yes". Would you maybe be able to help me do that? I need to point the second script to a specific sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet().getName(); // Get the sheet on which the change was made
  var sheetname = s.getName();

  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet

  var actionCol, nameCol, valueToCheck;

  switch (sheetname) {
    case "xxxx":
      actionCol = 19;
      nameCol = 18;
      valueToCheck = "Assigned";
      break;
    case "yyyy": 
      actionCol = 19;
      nameCol = 18;
      valueToCheck = "Assigned";
      break;
    default:
      return ; // if none of the names aboves, no instructions, so quit withoud doing anything
  }

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

  // if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
  if (e.value == valueToCheck && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      // or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
    }
  }
}
```

In the `switch` operation, just edit the values based on what you need, and repeat the `case` parts (until, including, the `break;` command) for each sheet you need to consider.